# R logic using dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, logic

I am working with the mtcars dataset in R and what I am trying to do is separate a list of cars from the original dataset whose "carb" values all == 1.

```
mtcars
attach(mtcars)
gc_1 <- c(mtcars[which(carb == 1),])
as.data.frame(gc_1)

   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
3 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
4 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
5 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
6 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
7 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
```

so for some reason cars 4, 5, and 7 have "carb" values != 1

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem.  It may be best not to attach the dataset.

Comment: how else would I be able to call "carb" values to see if they equal 1?

Comment: `mtcars[with(mtcars, carb==1),]`; or `subset(mtcars, carb==1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have a `carb` variable in your environment that's masking `mtcars$carb`. For example:

```
> attach(mtcars)
> carb <- 1:7
> mtcars[carb == 1,]
                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4          21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
Merc 240D          24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.19 20.00  1  0    4    2
Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.25 17.98  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger   15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.52 16.87  0  0    3    2
Ford Pantera L     15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.17 14.50  0  1    5    4
```

To make sure you are really working with `mtcars$carb`, make it explicit:

```
> mtcars[mtcars$carb == 1,]
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
```

Or you can delete `carb` first:

```
> rm(carb)
> mtcars[carb == 1,]
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
```

I also changed `mtcars[which(carb == 1),]` to `mtcars[carb == 1,]`, simpler.

Also, it seems a bit strange to put a data frame inside a `c(...)` vector. You can write your code like this instead:

```
gc_1 <- mtcars[mtcars$carb == 1,]
```